# Please help. I can't execute PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here, I can't execute my statement (into MySQL database)
no errors showing me.

I am getting data as array and passing into an object and trying to execute the statement.

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO courses (
category_id_fk, 
course_title, 
course_header_title, 
course_header_text, 
course_header_image, 
course_header_video, 
course_slogan_text, 
course_slogan_button_text,
course_description,
course_content,
category_active
) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
}

try{
$query->execute(array(
$data["category_name"], 
$data["course_title"], 
$data["course_header_title"], 
$data["course_header_text"],
$data["course_header_image"]["name"], 
$data["course_header_video"], 
$data["course_slogan_text"], 
$data["course_slogan_button_text"],
$data["course_description"], 
$data["course_content"], $data["category_active"]
));


}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}

if($query->rowCount() == 1){

header("Location: courses?msg=success");


}else{
echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the error mode to exception first.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: `PDO::setAttribute` takes two arguments

Answer (score 1):

GOT MY OWN ANSWER!

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

This showed me what was wrong when executing statement. my problem was: wrong field name.